# How to remove extra blank horizontal grid line in ganttchart?

Tags: pgfgantt, grids

I am having some problem with an extra blank horizontal grid line that appears in the gantt chart. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[hidelinks, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{pagecounting}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage[inner=25mm, outer=25mm, bottom=25mm, top=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-note,firstinits=true,doi=false, eprint=false, sorting=none, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=99]{biblatex}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
%\hspace*{-20px}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={*1{black}},hgrid={*1{black}}, x unit=0.6cm, y unit chart=0.5cm, bar top shift = -0.295mm,bar label node/.append style={align=left}]{1}{24}
{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
\gantttitlelist{1,...,24}{1}\\
\ganttbar[bar height=0.24mm,bar/.append style={fill=gray!20}]{1}{1}{4}\\
\ganttbar[bar height=0.24mm,bar/.append style={fill=gray!20}]{2}{5}{5}\\
\ganttbar[bar height=0.24mm,bar/.append style={fill=gray!20}]{2}{6}{8}\\
\ganttbar[bar height=0.24mm,bar/.append style={fill=gray!20}]{4}{9}{10}
}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and this is the output I get:

[image]

How can I remove the extra blank horizontal grid line in the bottom? Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "created" it and saw it after shifting via `bar top shift = -0.295mm,` .

To see it I did the following:

- removed all packages not required here
- put bars as a macro (short-hand notation) for comparision
- (the `%` at the end avoid unwanted spaces being inserted at "execution")
- commented out your ganttchart options until the troublemaker was found
- (to do so I put them line by line to use `%` to remove as needed
- show the result without and with  `bar top shift = -0.295mm,`

[image: compared]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

% removed packages, which are not needed here

\newcommand\bars[0]{% for short-hand notation
{%
\fontsize{8}{10}%
\selectfont%
\gantttitlelist{1,...,24}{1}\\%
\ganttbar[bar height=0.24mm,bar/.append style={fill=gray!20}]{1}{1}{4}\\%
\ganttbar[bar height=0.24mm,bar/.append style={fill=gray!20}]{2}{5}{5}\\%
\ganttbar[bar height=0.24mm,bar/.append style={fill=gray!20}]{2}{6}{8}\\%
\ganttbar[bar height=0.24mm,bar/.append style={fill=gray!20}]{4}{9}{10}%
}%
}

\begin{document}

% without bar top shift
\begin{figure}[h]
    %\hspace*{-20px}
    \begin{ganttchart}[
        vgrid={*1{black}},
        hgrid={*1{black}}, 
        x unit=0.6cm, 
        y unit chart=0.5cm, 
    %   bar top shift = -0.295mm,% <<< without
        bar label node/.append style={align=left}
        ]
        {1}
        {24}
        \bars{}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{figure}

% with
\begin{figure}[h]
    %\hspace*{-20px}
    \begin{ganttchart}[
        vgrid={*1{black}},
        hgrid={*1{black}}, 
        x unit=0.6cm, 
        y unit chart=0.5cm, 
        bar top shift = -0.295mm,% <<< with
        bar label node/.append style={align=left}
        ]
        {1}
        {24}
        \bars{}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer! Yes, it works. But then how can I remove the blank white line under the number months in your result? Thanks again.

Comment: When I skim through the manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt , it seems to be intended by design. Perhaps it's described in mor detail in ch." 2.5 Titles", if and how you can avoid the blank line.

Comment: Okay, I will check. One last question if possible: do you know how can I fill with color the cells of the gantttitle?

Comment: If you mean the bars, there are several options. E.g. search for color in the manual, or see ch. "2.7.4 Options: Progress" etc. // See also "2.3 The Canvas" to color the canvas (background). After all, pgfgantt is tikz, so whatever is missing you can add via tikz one way or the other. // Coloring specific cells from the grid: didn't find on a quick scan. // You may also want to search this site, e.g. via the tag: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfgantt .

Comment: Thanks. More precisely I meant the month cells. OK, I will try to find a way.

Comment: MS-SPO: Sorry, I have another question related to your result in the first answer. How can I centre the bars in the horizontal grids? Is there any precise command?

Comment: I have managed :)